# Interpolate JSON values into a string

Tags: java, json, string-interpolation

I am writing an application/class that will take in a template text file and a JSON value and return interpolated text back to the caller.

The format of the input template text file needs to be determined. For example: `my name is ${fullName}`

Example of the JSON:

```
{"fullName": "Elon Musk"}
```

Expected output:

```
"my name is Elon Musk"
```

I am looking for a widely used library/formats that can accomplish this.

1. What format should the template text file be?
2. What library would support the template text file format defined above and accept JSON values?

Its easy to build my own parser but there are many edge cases that needs to be taken care of and I do not want to reinvent the wheel.

For example, if we have a slightly complex JSON object with lists, nested values etc. then I will have to think about those as well and implement it.

Comment: This is all really simple stuff to do with javascript.  I can't think of any edge case that would be difficult to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I have always used org.json library. Found at http://www.json.org/.

It makes it really easy to go through JSON Objects.

For example if you want to make a new object:

```
JSONObject person = new JSONObject();
person.put("fullName", "Elon Musk");
person.put("phoneNumber", 3811111111);
```

The JSON Object would look like:

```
{
"fullName": "Elon Musk",
"phoneNumber": 3811111111
}
```

It's similar to retrieving from the Object

```
String name = person.getString("fullName");
```

You can read out the file with `BufferedReader` and parse it as you wish.
Hopefully I helped out. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how we do it.

```
Map inputMap = ["fullName": "Elon Musk"]
        String finalText = StrSubstitutor.replace("my name is \${fullName}", inputMap)
```

Comment: Thank you for the useful code. While this works, I am interested in a much complex use cases. I will update the question with an example case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this：
https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson

Fastjson is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation. It can also be used to convert a JSON string to an equivalent Java object. Fastjson can work with arbitrary Java objects including pre-existing objects that you do not have source-code of.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Java's String Templates feature.
It is described in [JEP 430](https://openjdk.org/jeps/430), and it appears in JDK 21 as a preview feature.  Here is an example use:

```java
String name = "Joan";
String info = STR."My name is \{name}";
assert info.equals("My name is Joan");   // true
```

Java's string templates are more versatile, and much safer, than features in other languagues such as C#'s string interpolation and Python's f-strings.
For example, here is a template processor that returns not strings but, rather, instances of JSONObject:

```java
var JSON = StringTemplate.Processor.of(
        (StringTemplate st) -> new JSONObject(st.interpolate())
    );

String name    = "Joan Smith";
String phone   = "555-123-4567";
String address = "1 Maple Drive, Anytown";
JSONObject doc = JSON."""
    {
        "name":    "\{name}",
        "phone":   "\{phone}",
        "address": "\{address}"
    };
    """;
```