# best way to do data driven testing with different req body using rest assured java

Tags: java, json, rest, rest-assured, data-driven-tests

I have a request body like

```
{
  "Data": {
    "Permissions": [
      "ReadOnly"
    ],

    "CreationTime": "2099-09-14T10:28:33.722Z",
      },
  "standards": {  },
  "testing":{  }
}
```

I want to run a data driven testing using rest assured where I pass different values for permissions and creation time etc.. What is the best way to do that ? I want to have only one request model but need to write a helper method to change the values by passing the field key name and value .
Very much appreciate your help

Comment: Showing your code

Comment: Try use interpolation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56570582/interpolate-json-values-into-a-string

Comment: @Roberto I want to just pass the key and value and it should change the value in the json where ever it may ..

Answer (score 0):

Either you can create property file (something like inputdata.properties) or using excel sheet also you can call the data and iterate through all the rows of excel sheet. You can follow below link :-

[https://www.callicoder.com/java-read-excel-file-apache-poi/](http://Iterate%20through%20excel%20data)